# Fetch excel formula components using python in *nixes

Tags: python, linux, xls, xlrd

I have .xlsx doculment - in microsoft excel format, with formula (sum) in one of its cells. I need to know which cells this formula depends on. How i can do this? I found that maybe xlrd module can help to solve this task, but i can't find right way.

Comment: but last comment of that question dated by Jul 27 '13 at 13:10, may be something changed

Comment: At that question there is an answer by the `xlrd` maintainer, comment there and get an update straight from the horse's mouth.